# Detect when child ref is changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following problem:

There is child component that accepts a ref passed down from the parent component:

```js
const ChildComp = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <div ref={ref} />)
```

The parent component creates an array of refs and assigns a ref in the array to one of the children:

```js
const ParentComp = () => {
 const items = [1,2,3]
 const refs = items.map(() => React.createRef()) 

 React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(refs);
 }, [refs])

 return <div>{items.map((item, index) => <ChildComp ref={refs[index]>)}</div>
}
```

However, when I output the state of the refs array in `useEffect`, it outputs it only once when the parent mounts and at that point the ref.current values are still null, because children are not mounted yet.

I would like to be able to have an array of refs where each ref belongs to a child as illustrated above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working Codesandbox:   https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-leaf-tpibl?file=/src/App.tsx

I modified your example a bit:

- use functional components only, as string refs (from `createRef`) should not be used with them
- use [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs) instead of creating them, which will react to changes of the node

The important part is

`refProp={(node) => (itemsRef.current[index] = node)}`,

which will fill the `itemsRef` array based on the callback ref through the `ChildComp`.

**ChildComp**

```
const ChildComp = ({
  number,
  refProp
}: {
  number: number;
  refProp: (node: HTMLDivElement) => void;
}) => {
  // simulate internal child state for demonstration
  const [childState, setChildState] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => setChildState(number * 2), [number]);

  return (
    <div ref={refProp}>
      <p>
        State from child no. {number}: {childState}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**ParentComp**

```
const ParentComp = () => {
  const [items] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  // you can access the elements with itemsRef.current[n]
  const itemsRef = useRef<Array<HTMLDivElement | null>>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // create initial refs array, will be filled through callback ref
    itemsRef.current = itemsRef.current.slice(0, items.length);
  }, [items]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // this logs the three <div>s of the childs
    console.log(itemsRef);
  }, [itemsRef]);

  return (
    <>
      <p>Hi from parent!</p>
      {items.map((_, index) => (
        <ChildComp
          key={index}
          number={index + 1}
          // will be called by React when they're changing
          refProp={(node) => (itemsRef.current[index] = node)}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe each ref in the `refs` array is changing but the array itself didn't change. this is why useEffect didn't run again.

You can try:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(refs);
 }, [refs[0].current])
```

Comment: This will also fire only once on mount.